# Azure deploy missing XML doc files from deployment target

Tags: azure, deployment

I have a solution. 2 projects within the solution produce XML documentation, that I need to copy to the bin folder web root when I deploy to azure.

Locally, I notice that when I build my solution, those 2 XML files get copied with the DLL into my web/bin folder. When I run my un-modified deploy.cmd file locally, I also notice that kudosync picks those up and hapilly puts them into my artifacts/wwwroot/bin folder.

But - when I deploy to azure by pushing to github, the local deployment temp folder on azure doesn't contain the XML files, and thus they don't get picked up. I added some post-build "DIR" commands to the deploy.cmd file to see what is going on, and the XML files just aren't there in the %DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%\bin\ folder.

Anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Aha - it's because when you build from MSBUILD, it doesn't generate the XML docs for the related projects. I was getting them locally because I'd at some point built from VS, which generated them.